# Profile does not exist. Instaloader

Tags: python, firebase, function, web-scraping, instaloader

I am trying to do scraping with the instaloader library in python in a firebase cloud function, but I have a strange behavior.

When I run my code in the local firebase emulator it works perfect and I save the account trackers, but when the function runs in production I get the following in console:

Error: Profile A does not exist.

The most similar profiles are: A, B, C, D, E.

Instaloader Version: instaloader==4.8.1

My code is as follows:

```
import random
import logging
import json
import instaloader
from firebase_init import db
from firebase_admin import firestore

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def get_profile_followers():
    try:
        profile_name = random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'])
        logging.info(f'Profile name selected: {profile_name}')

        # Obtener imágenes existentes
        doc_ref = db.collection('profiles').document('test')
        doc = doc_ref.get()
        existing_followers = doc.to_dict().get('followers', []) if doc.exists else []
        limit_value = doc.to_dict().get('limitFollowers', 100) if doc.exists else 100
        existing_followers_usernames = {follower['username'] for follower in existing_followers}
        followers_count = len(existing_followers)
        
        if followers_count >= 1300:
            logging.info(f'Limite de seguidores alcanzado: {followers_count}')
            return f'Limite de seguidores alcanzado: {followers_count}'
        else:
            # Se obtienen seguidores de la cuenta
            L = instaloader.Instaloader()
            L.load_session_from_file('account', filename=f'./mysessionfile')
            
            profile_followers = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, profile_name).get_followers()
            
            followers = []
            
            count = 0
            for follower in profile_followers:
                if count >= limit_value:
                    break
                
                if follower.username in existing_followers_usernames:
                    logging.info(f'Follower {follower.username} ya existe')
                    logging.info('=================')
                else:
                    follower_info = {
                        'username': follower.username,
                        'isPrivate': follower.is_private,
                    }
                    logging.info(f'Perfil Numero {count + 1}: {follower_info} guardado')
                    followers.append(follower_info)
                    count += 1
                
            doc_ref = db.collection('profiles').document('test')
            batch = db.batch()
            batch.update(doc_ref, {'followers': firestore.ArrayUnion(followers)})
            batch.commit()
            
            
            response_data = {
                'message': f'Seguidores de {profile_name} guardados',
                'Total': len(followers),
            }
            response_json = json.dumps(response_data)

            return f'Completed: {response_json}'
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error: {e}')
        return f'Error: {e}'
```

I was hoping it would start tracking each follower as it behaves in the local emulator:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-profile_scrap"
>  INFO:root:Profile name selected: 'profile_scraped'
>  Loaded session from ./mysessionfile.
>  INFO:root:Perfil Numero 1: {'username': 'A', 'isPrivate': True} guardado
>  INFO:root:Perfil Numero 2: {'username': 'B', 'isPrivate': False} guardado
>  INFO:root:Perfil Numero 3: {'username': 'C', 'isPrivate': True} guardado
>  INFO:root:Perfil Numero 4: {'username': 'D', 'isPrivate': True} guardado
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% positive but I suspect the issue is that you are trying to write a file to the current directory (`./mysessionfile`) but in the cloud instance you are limited as to where your code can write files.  See [this section of the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#memory-file-system).  Most places I've seen talking about writing files in Cloud Functions recommend writing to `/tmp`.